# Regular Expression Failure javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any reason the following string should fail the regular expression below?

String: `"http://devices/"`

Expression:

```
/^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|www.|pop:\/\/|imap:\/\/){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)/.test(input.val())
```

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: This should show you why http://www.regexper.com/#%5E(http%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%7Chttps%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%7Cftp%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%7Cwww.%7Cpop%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F%7Cimap%3A%5C%2F%5C%2F)%7B1%7D(%5B0-9A-Za-z%5D%2B%5C.)

Comment: ^^^ that was the coolest thing I've seen all day

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will fail because of the last dot `.` in your regular expression.

```
/^  ...  \.)/
         ^^
```

There is not one in the string you are validating against.

```
http://devices 
              ^ Should be a dot, not a forward slash
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bO4zK9/1)

If you are planning on using regex to do this, I would probably prefer using a [RegExp Object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp) to avoid all the escaping, or group the prefixes together using a non-capturing group.

```
/^((?:https?|ftp|pop|imap):\/{2}|www\.)  ...  $/
```

Answer (score 0):

The last character in the string must be a period. see "\." at the end of the regex.

You can use http://rubular.com/ to test simple regex expressions and what their matches are.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's failing is because, you are using:

```
^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|www.|pop:\/\/|imap:\/\/){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)
```

and you should use:

```
^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|www.|pop:\/\/|imap:\/\/){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+.)
                                     You don't have to escape . --------^
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the regex with a `$`.

On this two last: `.)`, this dot should be optional, as it is needed to validade.

to satisfy this `"http://devices/"` the regex in java at least is:

```
^((http://)|(https://)|(ftp://)|(pop://)|(imap://)){1}(www.)?([0-9A-Za-z]+)(.)?([0-9A-Za-z]+)?$
```

Are those `/` at the beggining and the end code delimiters?